# How to pass a big array of intergers from ObjC to JS?

Tags: ios, javascriptcore

Currently we pass data from ObjC to JS as huge string where all integers are converted to string and comma separated. Is there a better way? I browsed through many questions here on SO that I thought could be relevant, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616641/javascriptcore-external-arrays) someone mentions that:

> The build of JavaScriptCore that comes with iOS 7 does have typed arrays, but unfortunately the public API doesn't expose them so you can't touch their data from native.

I wonder if that's true or if there is another way? Maybe call JS function with an array as an argument that would translate in to an array argument? Or it could be translated into a lot of arguments and then `Fucntion.arguments` used.

Comment: I was under the impression that the `JavaScriptCore.framwork` was still a private API for iOS and only available for OSX? I've given a bit of a google and whilst I can find questions related to it there is zero documentation for the framework like there is for every other public framework apple have released (Note I know there is documentation for the Mac version)

Comment: @Popeye good point, but check SO you will find that somewhere earlier this year (or late 2013) something has changed and people started to integrate this API into their iOS apps intensively. There is no official tutorial or sane reference, only header files and some third party tutorials and hacks.

Comment: Yeah I saw a bit about it on SO however no one has actually shown anything from Apple to say this can now be used and everything that I can find still relates to it being a private API. Also Apple are very good at documenting their public APIs and there is zero documentation for this on iOS so this would say to me that it is still private. Just because it is talked about on SO and there is all of a sudden a visible header file doesn't mean that it public, the header could have just been made visible for something Apple have done. I'd be very careful about using it.

Comment: JavaScriptCore is indeed public as of iOS 7 - check WWDC 2013 Session 615.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the JSContext ObjC API, you can simply pass a NSArray of NSNumber objects to JavaScriptCore and it'll automatically convert it to a JavaScript array of numbers. While not as efficient as typed arrays by far, it should be better than slicing strings.